# Python: For loop with files, how to grab the next line within forloop?

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I have a file that I want to get each line at a time, but once it gets to a specific line, I need to get the next few lines information.

Here is a code sample:

```
rofile = open('foo.txt', 'r')
for line in rofile:
    print line
    if(line.strip() == 'foo'):
        line = line.next()
        print line
        line = line.next()
        print line
        line = line.next()
        print line
```

When I come back around and loop for the second time, that first print statement should print the 5th line in the file. Is there any possible way to do this?

EDIT: Sorry for not clarifying the details. `rofile` is a file object that I'm iterating through. Whether `next()` is the real method to obtain the next line when using a file, I don't know. I don't have much experience with file manipulation in python.

Comment: If your first line equals 'foo' (might want to change that to `if line.rstrip() == 'foo')`, does this not already on the 2nd iteration, print the 5th line?

Comment: `line.next()` will not work in py 3.x , consider using `next(line)`, works in both. Though `next(line)` might not work in ancient python versions 2.5 or earlier.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `iter` to convert your object into an iterable which supports `next`.

```
irofile = iter(rofile)
for line in irofile:
    print line
    if(line == 'foo'):
        line = next(irofile)  #BEWARE, This could raise StopIteration!
        print line
```

As pointed out in the comments, if your object is already an iterator, then you don't need to worry about `iter` (this is the case with `file` objects).  However, I leave it here as it works for the case of any arbitrary iterable (e.g. `list`s).

Comment: I think file object is an iterator itself, so no use of `iter()`.

Comment: Also, if the OP wants the next 3 lines, he can simply do `for k, n_line in zip(range(3), the_file):`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Of course -- If the iterable object supports `next` already then you don't need `iter`, but it doesn't hurt anyway.  I was trying to answer this slightly more generally.

Comment: @Bakuriu -- Yep, that would work too if you can process each of those lines the same way.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but considering fact that OP was using `.next()`, so he was already iterating over an iterator. +1.

Comment: @JonClements I was about to suggest `islice()` only. :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of object that `rofile` is, I can think of a couple of ways to do this.

#### List of strings

If you can get it to be simply a list of strings that make up the lines of the file:

```
for index, line in enumerate(rofile):
   if line == 'foo':
       for a in range(index, index + HOW_MANY_LINES_YOU_WANT):
           print rofile[a]
```

#### Iterable

If the file is already an iterable:

```
for line in rofile:
    print line
    if line == 'foo':
        for a in range(3): # Just do it 3 times
            print line.next()
            # After this happens and the for loop is restarted,
            # it will print the line AFTER
```

You can see in this quickie example I wrote that it'll work this way as an iterable:

```
>>> k = iter([1,2,3,4])
>>> for a in k:
    print 'start loop'
    print a
    if a == 2:
        print 'in if'
        print k.next()
        print 'end if'
    print 'end loop'


start loop
1
end loop
start loop
2
in if
3
end if
end loop
start loop
4
end loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `for` loop if you don't actually want to do something *for* every line. One option might be:

```
try:
    while True:
        line = file.next()
        #do stuff
        if line == 'foo':
            #do other stuff
except(StopIteration):
     #go on with your life
```

Comment: OP _does_ want to do something for every line, though--note the `print line` statement right under the `for` loop.

Comment: This probably would be a better implementation. Thanks!!

Comment: @jdotjdot: See the sentence immediately after the sample:

"When I come back around and loop for the second time, that first print statement should print the 5th line in the file."

Some lines aren't supposed to hit that `print line` statement, because they're taken care of by the `if foo` block.

Comment: @PeterBB Yes, but ultimately, they're all hit by a `print` statment, since even in the `if foo` block, the lines go to `print`.  Maybe that's just his generalized example, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it for a file object:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as rofile:
    for line in rofile:
        print line,
        if line.strip() == 'foo':
            for _ in xrange(3):  # get the next 3 lines
                try:
                    line = rofile.next()
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                print line,
```

The try/except is needed in case there aren't 3 more lines after a 'foo' line is seen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and using the `continue` statement instead worked in my case